# Make new line above last line and add something there

Tags: text-processing, awk, osx

Like a reverse of `awk 'NR==2 {print ""} 1` which adds a new line under the first and prints whatever there. I can't replace the number after `NR==` with a fixed value because I want to be able to do this at file including any amount of lines. I mean I suppose I could do something that counts the amount of lines and then make a variable which is the number of the second last line, but I don't want to "reinvent the wheel".

Example input:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Example output:

```
1
2
3
something added here
4
```

Comment: I meant `sed '$i\something'` (there's a newline after the backslash)..

Answer (score 0):

You could delay printing by a line, and then use an `END` block:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print line} {line = $0} END {printf "%s\n%s\n", "something added here", line}'
```

I save the current line in `line`, and then print in the next iteration. In the `END` block, therefore, `line` is the last line, which has not been printed yet.

```
$ printf "%s\n" {1..4} | awk 'NR > 1{print line} {line = $0} END {printf "%s\n%s\n", "something added here", line}'
1
2
3
something added here
4
```